# How to calculate the IOU of polygons in python?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, opencv

I have two polygons.
polygon1:[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]...[xn,yn]]
polygon2:[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]...[xm,ym]]
the num of n and m might be the same or not.
How to calculate the IOU of two polygons? Or how to calculate the overlap area and area of polygon1 and polygon2 ? So I can compute Area of overlap / (Area P1 + Area P2)

Comment: Some ideas in this SX question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237053/getting-intersection-of-multiple-polygons-efficiently-in-python

Answer (score 6):

The [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html) library has everything you need. As @pink_spikyhairman commented, there are many question examples of how to use this library to calculate IOU of polygons. So for example, you have your two polygons, a square and a triangle:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polygon1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
polygon2 = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)])
intersect = polygon1.intersection(polygon2).area
union = polygon1.union(polygon2).area
iou = intersect / union
print(iou)  # iou = 0.5
```

Comment: Hint: polygon1.area + polygon2.area - intersec is slightly faster