# How to Calculate the Intersection over Union (IoU) loss between predicted polygons and target polygons with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, loss-function, torchvision

I am trying to calculate the IOU of two polygons consisting of 3000 2d points as a loss function. I have seen answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61577406/how-to-calculate-the-iou-of-polygons-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847477/calculate-intersection-over-union-of-two-predictions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67682106/compare-two-segmentation-maps-predictions) but they use python libs, not torch.

I was trying to achieve that using torch operations. My code is as follows

```
import torch

def calculate_iou_loss(pred_polygons, target_polygons):
    """
    Calculate the Intersection over Union (IoU) loss between predicted polygons and target polygons.

    Args:
        pred_polygons (torch. Tensor): Predicted polygons of shape (batch_size, num_points).
        target_polygons (torch.Tensor): Target polygons of shape (batch_size, num_points).

    Returns:
        torch.Tensor: IoU loss.
    """
    # Calculate the intersection points
    intersection = torch.sum(pred_polygons & target_polygons, dim=1)

    # Calculate the union points
    union = torch.sum(pred_polygons | target_polygons, dim=1)

    # Calculate the IoU loss
    iou_loss = 1 - torch.mean(intersection / union)

    return iou_loss
```

But I get this error

```
RuntimeError: bitwise_and(): functions with out=... arguments don't support automatic differentiation, but one of the arguments requires grad.
```

It's because **bitwise_and** operation does not support automatic differentiation. I have tried element-wise multiplication (*) but got the same error. The rest of the code is as follows

```
pred_polygons, target_polygons = torch.array() # shaped (24, 6000) [ x1,x2,x3,...y1,y2,y3]
loss = calculate_iou_loss(pred_polygons, target_polygons)
loss.backwards()
```

Is there any way to fix the code to calculate IOU for the polygons for object localisation task?